# Candle stick chart with moving average in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

When I run this code, I get the error "Error using ReadTableMinMaxMovingAverage 
Data inputs must match the axis configuration. A numeric axis must have numeric data inputs or
data inputs which can be converted to double".
Please advise.

```
        Low_Gate=tbl.PX_LOW;
        High_Gate=tbl.PX_HIGH;
        Open_Gate=tbl.PX_OPEN;
        Last_Gate=tbl.PX_LAST;


        meridian_price=(Low_Gate+High_Gate)/2;
        ma_medianPrice13 = movavg(meridian_price,'simple',13);
        ma_medianPrice8 = movavg(meridian_price,'simple',8);
        ma_medianPrice5 = movavg(meridian_price,'simple',5);


        %candle(High_Gate,Low_Gate,Last_Gate,Open_Gate)
        grid on
        hold on
        plot(Date,ma_medianPrice13)
        plot(Date,ma_medianPrice8)
        plot(Date,ma_medianPrice5)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please edit your question to make your problem reproducable. Nobody can answer this without further information. In addition it might also help if you explain what you are trying to do. For guidance please read [how to ask questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to create a minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to (1) be self-contained: create example data to plot rather than load a file we don’t have; (2) be minimal: figure out what the smallest code is you need to recreate the error, one of the `plot` functions (I presume) throws the error, you don’t need the other ones; and (3) include the full error message, copy-paste it into your question. Thanks!

Comment: Hello Chris I just edited my post, I want to make a candlestick chart with the movavg graph in one plot.

Comment: it sounds like the issue is with your data which we do not have access to

Comment: So basically you say that it should plot the moving average graph along with the candlestick chart with no problem?

Comment: I think the main problem is that the candlestick char has a numeric data type and the other plots has a "DateTime" data type, which can cause an error, still can't solve this issue.